# Struggling with Haskell type system

Tags: haskell, types, sqrt

I am trying to learn some Haskell by doing basic tasks in the particular case I am trying to implement some basic function for primality check, but I really can figure out the types, my code is

```
isPrime :: (Num a) => a -> Bool
isPrime n
    | n <= 1 = False
    | otherwise = not $ 0 `elem` map (mod n) [2..m] where m = floor $ sqrt n
```

I tried instead of `(Num a) => a` to use different number types or to use `sqrt` with `fromIntegral` but I still get error messages, like:

```
*Could not deduce (Floating a) arising from a use of `sqrt'
  from the context: Num a
    bound by the type signature for:
               isPrime :: forall a. Num a => a -> Bool
    at Helpers.hs:5:1-31
  Possible fix:
    add (Floating a) to the context of
      the type signature for:
        isPrime :: forall a. Num a => a -> Bool
* In the second argument of `($)', namely `sqrt n'
  In the expression: floor $ sqrt n
  In an equation for `m': m = floor $ sqrt n
| otherwise = not $ 0 `elem` map (mod n) [2..m] where m = floor $ sqrt n
```

I can really use some help here, thank you in advance.

Comment: "Possible fix:
    add (Floating a) to the context of
      the type signature for:
        isPrime" have you tried this?

Comment: Note that you can't use `fromIntegral` on a `Num a` either, since you can't guarantee that `a` is integral!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems in your code:

1. Incompatible types.

Calling both `sqrt n` and `(mod n)` reqiure n to be both `Floating` and `Integral` at the same time.

2. Insufficient context. Requiring only `(Num a)` does not allow neither of the operations.

A possible fix would be: a) narrow down type context to a much more concise `(Integral a)`; b) add `fromIntegral` to `sqrt`'s argument:

```
isPrime :: Integral a => a -> Bool
isPrime n
    | n <= 1 = False
    | otherwise = not $ 0 `elem` map (mod n) [2..m] where m = floor $ sqrt $fromIntegral n
```

Comment: I don't know why, but I really thought that (Num a) allows a more broad set of operations, I really should've checked that. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: It would be more accurate to say that `Num` provides a narrow set of operations and therefore a broad range of implications.

Comment: Or maybe, `Num` is the most basic numeric class that has subclasses with empty intersection.

Answer (score 4):

As others have mentioned, the use of `mod` requires `a` to be `Integral`, and the use of `sqrt` requires `a` to be `Floating`. Judging by the name of your function, I'm assuming that you want to use it on integral types.
So, you can fix this by changing your signature to `isPrime :: (Integral a) => a -> Bool`, then precomposing `sqrt` with `fromIntegral`. You could do something like

```
where m = floor . sqrt . fromIntegral $ n
```

Another option would be to replace `[1..m]` with something like `takeWhile (\x -> x * x <= n) [1..]` to avoid the need for `Floating`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue the compiler is describing is that you're applying incompatible operations to the same type: `mod` requires [`Integral a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Integral), `sqrt` requires [`Floating a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Floating), and no type satisfies both. You could work around that using type conversions like `fromIntegral` and `ceiling`, but you'd want to be careful to avoid rounding errors. For my test, I removed the type constraint and used `m = ceiling $ sqrt $ fromIntegral n`, which led to the inferred type `isPrimeSqrt :: Integral a => a -> Bool`.

Another approach is to consider why the conflict was hit and look for other solutions. The reason for `sqrt` is to produce an optimized stopping point for the test. Can we find that stopping point in another manner?

As it turns out, while division is expensive, it frequently produces two results: the quotient and remainder. With `mod` you're looking for the latter, but we have [`divMod`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:divMod) and [`quotRem`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:quotRem) which produce both. So it could be worth testing if that's notably slower than the plain `mod` test ([benchmark results](http://donkey.vernier.se/~yann/hs-bench/prime.html), comparing `[2..]` vs `[2..m]`).

```
isPrime n = (n > 1) && null (filter isFactor (takeWhile notTooHigh divisors))
  where notTooHigh (divisor,quotient,_) = divisor <= quotient
        isFactor (_,_,remainder) = remainder == 0
        divisors = [(divisor,quotient,remainder) |
                    divisor <- 2:[3,5..],
                    let (quotient,remainder) = quotRem n divisor]
```

Comment: I didn't test for extremely large primes, where the quotient storage may take more time and the square root actually runs into rounding issues. That should happen past about `2^53`.